# "Failed to fetch... Temporary failure resolving..." when trying to install

Tags: apt

I am unable to install apache. I get these errors when I try to install it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please attach text to your question; not provide a much-harder-to-read picture of text I can't copy/paste into a browser, to check its available to help assist you.  Edit your question and paste there please.

Comment: What command did you type ? What version of Ubuntu are you using ? With the informations you gave it will be hard to help you

Answer (score 1):

The screen-shot you shared shows 'Failed to Fetch'. This generally happens because of either you have not updated the sources list using:
`sudo apt update`

or, try accessing one of the URL from terminal, copy and paste it in a browser and hit enter, to make sure you're connected to Internet and you're able to access that server.

Please update your question if issue persists. So we can update the answer.

Comment: Hi, its coming error when I use this command and again 'Failed to Fetch'

Comment: Yeah, I just checked my internet is not working in Ubuntu